# Search for a field that contains ampersand mark

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a field that contains values such as

```
fish & chips
```

When I try to search for this field

```
Select * From Menu WHERE FoodItem = 'fish & chips'
```

It returns nothing despite all the matching entries in the table.

Now I realised this is an issue with the ampersand(&) mark. One workaround would be to change all 'fish & chips' to 'fish and chips'. But I would rather not play with that many data.

Also, I don't want to use LIKE or CONTAINS because I want to match things exactly.

How can I write a WHERE statement that will work with the & mark?

Thanks!
Cheers!

Comment: can you try this `Select * From Menu WHERE replace(FoodItem,'&','and') = replace('fish & chips','&','and')`

Comment: [I can't reproduce this.](http://rextester.com/IKOIO58999) Can you [edit] your question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: Hi masSTAShuFu, Thank you so much for the prompt response. Your solution works with a normal query. But now when I put it in to a Stored Procedure it doesnt work again 
Select * From Menu WHERE replace(FoodItem,'&','and') = replace(@searchingItem,'&','and')

Comment: Nothing in SQL Server will prevent ampersands from being evaluated as expected in equality predicates. Try your query from SSMS.

Comment: can you post your stored procedure

Comment: can you not just use WHERE FoodItem LIKE 'fish _ chips' ?

Comment: but yes, there is nothing that would prevent this in SQL Server, also a bit confused as to why you would want a procedure for a singular query like this.

Answer (score 1):

Some information is missing. It simply just works given the description of information provided unless you've got a `trigger` or something that is stripping the `&` on `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.

Verify that the data in the table actually still contains the `&`.

For example, as you can see [here](http://rextester.com/ONIA23741), searching on that character in your string is returning as it should.